# Wordpress 3.2 has broken my TinyMCE code

Tags: tinymce, updates

My code was working up until the 3.2 update, where I noticed that tinyMCE has been updated too.

Does anyone have any ideas why this may not work now? I don't get any console errors but I don't get any tinyMCE editors on the page either!

**CLARIFICATION: every instance of the TinyMCE editor has disappeared!**

**FURTHER CLARIFICATION: this is only occurring on my custom post type pages where I have custom instances of the TinyMCE editor. I still have the default "theEditor" MCE on the default Posts area.**

```
function meta_genus_species() {
    global $post;

    $genus = get_post_custom_values( 'genus', $post->ID );
    $species = get_post_custom_values( 'species', $post->ID );
    $etymology = get_post_custom_values( 'etymology', $post->ID );
    $family = get_post_custom_values( 'family', $post->ID );
    $common_names = get_post_custom_values( 'common_names', $post->ID );

    if (!isset($id)) { $id = "etymology"; }
    if (!isset($temp_min)) { $temp_min = plugins_url('images/temp_max.png' , __FILE__); }
    if (!isset($temp_max)) { $temp_max = plugins_url('images/temp_min.png' , __FILE__); }
    if (!isset($pH_min)) { $pH_min = plugins_url('images/pH_max.png' , __FILE__); }
    if (!isset($pH_max)) { $pH_max = plugins_url('images/pH_max.png' , __FILE__); }

$tinyMCE = <<<EOT
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $("#{$id}").addClass("mceEditor");
            if ( typeof( tinyMCE ) == "object" &&
                 typeof( tinyMCE.execCommand ) == "function" ) {
              tinyMCE.settings = {
                theme : "advanced",
                mode : "none",
                language : "en",
                height:"75",
                width:"100%",
                theme_advanced_layout_manager : "SimpleLayout",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,temp_min,temp_max,pH_min,pH_max",
                theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
                theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
                setup : function(ed) {
                    ed.addButton('temp_min', {
                        title : 'Temperature: Minimum',
                        image : '{$temp_min}',
                        onclick : function() {
                            ed.focus();
                            ed.selection.setContent('[temp_min]');
                        }
                    }),
                    ed.addShortcut("ctrl+1", "temp_min", "temp_min"),
                    ed.addButton('temp_max', {
                        title : 'Temperature: Maximum',
                        image : '{$temp_max}',
                        onclick : function() {
                            ed.focus();
                            ed.selection.setContent('[temp_max]');
                        }
                    }),
                    ed.addButton('pH_min', {
                        title : 'pH: Minimum',
                        image : '{$pH_min}',
                        onclick : function() {
                            ed.focus();
                            ed.selection.setContent('[pH_min]');
                        }
                    }),
                    ed.addButton('pH_max', {
                        title : 'pH: Maximum',
                        image : '{$pH_max}',
                        onclick : function() {
                            ed.focus();
                            ed.selection.setContent('[pH_max]');
                        }
                    });
                }
              };
              tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", true, "{$id}");
            }
        });
    </script>
EOT;
    echo $tinyMCE;

    ?>
<div class="meta_control normal">
    <p>Description of taxonomy.</p>
    <div class="box">
        <label>Genus</label>
        <p>
            <input name="genus" class="text" value="<?php if(isset($genus[0])) { echo esc_attr( $genus[0] ); } ?>" />
            <span>Testing...</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <label>Species</label>
        <p>
            <input name="species" class="text"  value="<?php if(isset($species[0])) { echo esc_attr( $species[0] ); } ?>" />
            <span>Testing...</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <p>
        <label>Etymology</label>
        <textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="etymology" id="etymology"><?php if(isset($etymology[0])) { echo esc_attr( $etymology[0] ); } ?></textarea>
        <span>Description</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Family</label>
        <input name="family" class="text"  value="<?php if(isset($family[0])) { echo esc_attr( $family[0] ); } ?>" />
        <span>Description</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Common Names</label>
        <input name="common_names" class="text"  value="<?php if(isset($common_names[0])) { echo esc_attr( $common_names[0] ); } ?>" />
        <span>Description</span>
    </p>
</div>
    <?php

}

function meta_authored() {
    global $post;

    $species_author = get_post_custom_values( 'species_author', $post->ID );
    $year_described = get_post_custom_values( 'year_described', $post->ID );

    ?>
<div class="meta_control side">
    <label>Species Author</label>
    <p>
        <input name="species_author" class="text" value="<?php if(isset($species_author[0])) { echo esc_attr( $species_author[0] ); } ?>" />
    </p>
    <label>Year Described</label>
    <p>
        <input name="year_described" class="text" value="<?php if(isset($year_described[0])) { echo esc_attr( $year_described[0] ); } ?>" />
    </p>
</div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: What exactly stopped working? Did the button disappear, etc.?

Comment: Sorry, should've made that more clear. Every instance of the editor has disappeared!

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue with one of my custom post types also. If the `supports` parameter of `register_post_type()` includes `editor` then everything works fine, but if it doesn't then TinyMCE doesn't even get registered to `$wp_scripts`. I'll add a bounty to the question to see if anyone can find an answer. It seems like a lot of changes were made in 3.2, but I haven't been able to pinpoint which ones would cause this.

Comment: Are you using the old WordPress Automatic Upgrade plugin instead of the native built-in updater? If so, disable the old plugin, go to Dashboard->Updates, and do a re-install. The old plugin does an incomplete upgrade of TinyMCE, resulting in all sorts of weirdness.

Comment: I'm not sure about Ian but I used the native updater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [some info on changes in 3.2](http://dannyvankooten.com/450/tinymce-wysiwyg-editor-in-wordpress-plugin/) that might be relevant:

> Aparrently, `wp_tiny_mce_preload_dialogs()` no longer exists from WP3.2 on. It got replaced by `wp_preload_dialogs()` which is now being called from `wp_quicktags()`. `wp_quicktags`, on his turn, is being called from `the_editor()` function. So, if you’re using `the_editor()` you no longer need to manually call the function to preload any dialogs!
>
> If you’re not using `the_editor()`, make sure to call `wp_preload_dialogs()` somewhere from your footer in the following manner:
>
> `wp_preload_dialogs( array( 'plugins' => 'wpdialogs,wplink,wpfullscreen' ) );`

You could try calling wp_preload_dialogs(), or maybe switch to using `the_editor()` instead of `tinyMCE.execCommand()`.

Also, check out [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22466/tinymce-in-custom-metabox-not-loaded-after-upgrading-from-wp-3-1-4-to-wp-3-2/23086#23086); calling `wp_tiny_mce()` solved my problem.

---

**Update**: [wp_tiny_mce() might be deprecated in 3.3](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17144).

Comment: Ian, thanks so much for posting again. I'm investigating now, so I'll update soon.

Comment: Woooohoooo, it works! The link you gave me in the last sentence, to "this question", fixed my problems. Thank you SO much Ian!

Comment: Sweet, I'm glad that fixed your problem too :)

Answer (score 2):

The possibility that your custom TinyMCE code broke you theme is pretty, but please - *before* trying to change or debug it - deactivate your plugins first and - if it doesn't help - switch to the default theme and see if it works.

Then take a look at your `meta_genus_species()` function and start commenting out the `ed.addButton` blocks of code. See if it works. If it does, uncomment one, check the result, uncomment the next one, etc.

Comment: Thanks kaiser. This isn't for a theme, it's for a number of custom plugins which I'm writing to use WordPress as my CMS. However, your point is still valid and as soon as I sit down to do some work tonight I'll try blocking out the code to pin-point the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with WP 3.2 and the Visual Editor

Try this:

> Anyway, for us, our fix was to open up wp-admin/admin-footer.php and
>   comment out line 36

```
do_action('admin_footer', '');
```

Read this: http://documentation.diyartportfolios.com/visual-editor-not-workin

and this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/upgraded-to-32-visual-editor-buttons-missing

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks for that - I've given it a go to no avail. I should probably clarify further that I have the editor as usual in the "Posts" section, just not in my custom post types pages.

Comment: Making changes to core WP files is never a good answer.

Comment: I upgraded to 3.2.1 and it solved the no Visual Editor Problem. It may help your problem, as well.

Comment: You got me excited there daniel, but unfortunately it hasn't resolved my problems. Thanks anyway :)